# Android: Attach an audio effect to global output mix

Tags: android, audio

I'd like to make the sound louder on my phone because I have bad hearing. I found many posts on this popular topic, but no solution worked with my Samsung S9 (Android 10):

- Set "getAudioSessionId = 0" is depricated and doesn't work (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63076046/is-it-possible-to-access-the-audio-output-stream-after-it-has-been-mixed-with-an), from 2020)
- Add a broadcast receiver for "android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION" (see [here](/questions/56803531/equalizing-the-audio-of-another-app-how-to) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404776/preferred-way-to-attach-audioeffect-to-global-mix)) does not work with all audio sources
- etc.

How can I achieve this goal, because there are quite a few apps in the Play Store that can do this (keyword "loudness booster")?

Thanks in advance.

```
loudnessEnhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(0);  //no effects, deprecated
loudnessEnhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId()); //works only with my own audio from mediaPlayer
loudnessEnhancer.setTargetGain(1000);
loudnessEnhancer.setEnabled(true);
```